# Is it worth implementing anything other than DirectSound output?

Tags: audio, directsound, winmm

I'm writing an audio application for Windows users. Currently audio is dumped to the soundcard via DirectSound. Is there any reason why this might fail on a typical desktop requiring a fallback to Multi Media Extensions (WinMM.dll), or will users (XP+) typically have DirectSound compatible drivers?